# How do I do availability checking right before declaring a global variable in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, compatibility

I need to check for availability of iOS 10 in my app before declaring the **center** variable.

This is my App Delegate:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {

    var center: UNUserNotificationCenter!
```

I don't want the @available attribute to enclose the entire class - only this variable declaration.

I know that you can check availability using the following code but this is not allowed outside a function.

```
 if #available(iOS 10, *)  {
 } else {
 // not available
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Availability check is not available for stored properties but it is for computed properties:

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
var center: UNUserNotificationCenter{
    return UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
 var center: UNUserNotificationCenter? {
        if #available(iOS 10, *)  {
            return UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
```